# Github sends email notification with different username upon my commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit

#### My actions

I recently created a new branch, made some commits (a simple `git commit -m`), and created a pull request in a repo that was not created by me. Github correctly recognises my username/email from `~/.gitconfig`, but sends email notifications containing the wrong username.

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
# Please adapt and uncomment the following lines:
name = ddelange
email = 14880945+ddelange@users.noreply.github.com
```

---

#### The results

As can be seen below, the commits are linked to me (as expected). Running `git show 2f74892` also looks as expected.
[image: Commits are received correctly so it seems]

---

#### However

Then, all people involved receive an **un**expected email from `notifications@github.com`, attributing my commit to the owner of the repo:
[image: Email containing wrong username]

---

These emails are sent every time I `git push`. Anyone ideas what's happening here?

Comment: That's very odd. I would contact GitHub support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I contaced Github support as Justin Howard suggested. This was their response:

> Hi there David,
>
> Thank you for getting back to us with that.
>
> I had a look at our logs for the repository and I do show @yrik
>   pushing that commit.
>
> We're attributing them to your account as you have your user.email set
>   correctly but Git is authenticating as the other user. This is
>   probably because you have that user's credentials cached in Keychain.
>
> Can you follow the steps below and let me know if that helps you to
>   resolve this?
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain
>
> Thanks, Steve

Removing (my) credentials from the keychain, and logging into git cli again [with 2fa](https://gist.github.com/ateucher/4634038875263d10fb4817e5ad3d332f) stopped the erroneous notifications.

Since I have notifications for "my own activity" disabled, and I'm not watching the repository otherwise, I now don't get notifications anymore when I push commits, and other watching users receive correct email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to check the ssh key configured on your system. In my case, the issue arose from the fact that I had registered a new identity on my system using ssh-add. When I added back my old private key, the issue got corrected.